# why did Django not create the dateTime field of the DB model?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, datetime, pycharm

I wrote the model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
     content = models.TextField()
     email = models.EmailField()
```

when I run the migrate it creates the table in the db.sqlite3 file but with no dateTime field (it does it also for date Field).
and in the admin site when I try to accsess the blog table it throws an exeption 'no such column' with the direct cause:

```
django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute
 86.   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) 

django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute
 396.  return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
```

I run the 'sqlmigrate' (after 'makemigration' and 'migrate') in the terminal and it shows that the date is in there and also in the migration file, but no dateTime field in the database!:

```
>manage.py sqlmigrate blog 0001
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Blog
--
CREATE TABLE "blog_blog" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "title" varchar(20) NOT NULL, "date" datetime NOT NULL, "content" text
NOT NULL, "email" varchar(254) NOT NULL);
COMMIT;
```

does someone knows why?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  That model does not contain a field named `dateTime`, so why would you expect migrate to create one?

Comment: Please run "sqlite3 db.sqlite3" and post the output of "SELECT * FROM blog_blog;".